# Clustering text data based on sentiment?

Tags: python, nlp, sentiment-analysis, multiclass-classification, unsupervised-learning

I am scraping reviews off Amazon with the intent to perform sentiment analysis to classify them into **positive**, **negative** and **neutral**. Now the data I would get would be text and unlabeled.

My approach to this problem would be as following:-

1.) Label the data using clustering algorithms like **DBScan**, **HDBScan** or **KMeans**. The number of clusters would obviously be 3.

2.) Train a **Classification** algorithm on the labelled data.

Now I have never performed clustering on text data but I am familiar with the basics of clustering. So my question is:

1. Is my approach correct?
2. Any articles/blogs/tutorials I can follow for text based clustering since I am kinda new to this?

Comment: Have you had a look into https://www.nltk.org ? That will do the sentiment analysis for you itself :)

Comment: I am familiar with the nltk library. But my issue is how to perform clustering on textual data. I am familiar with clustering on string and numerical data but not text data.

Answer (score 1):

I have never done such an experiment but as far as I know, the most challenging part of this work is transforming the `sentences` or `documents` into fixed-length vectors (mapping into semantic space). I highly suggest using a sentiment analysis pipeline from `huggingface` library for embedding the sentences (in this way you might exploit some supervision). There are other options as well:

1. Using `sentence-transformers` library. (straightforward and still good)
2. Using BoW. (simplest way but hard to get what you want)
3. Using TF-IDF (still simple but may simply do the work)

After you reach this point (every review ==> fixed-length vector) you can exploit whatever you want to cluster them and look after the results.